# Sequence of polynomials converging to $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence

Is there a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $\frac{1}{z}$ in $K:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid 1<|z|<2\}$?

My first attempt was to use the theorem of Runge which would apply if $K$ would be compact and $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ connected. As $K$ is not closed, it is not compact. But if I consider the closure $\bar{K}$, then $\mathbb{C}\setminus\bar{K}$ is not connected? So the Theorem can not be applied here? Any other hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Runge's theorem cannot be applied directly. And for good reason, the answer is no.

Consider the circle around $0$ with radius $3/2$. 
Pick one of the approximating polynomials that are very close to $1/z$, say the error is at most $\varepsilon<0.001$. 
Integrating this polynomial and $1/z$ on the circle, the difference between the integrals is at most $2\cdot (3/2)\cdot \pi\cdot \varepsilon<0.01$.

The integral of any polynomial is $0$ on any circle. 
But that of $1/z$ on the given circle is $2\pi i$.

This leads to a contradiction.

This example points out why the conectedness condition is important in Runge's theorem. Otherwise, some poles could present problems.

Comment: Thanks I understand your approach! But why is the integral of $1/z$ not $2\pi i$ by Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: I messed it up, you are right.